# Determinism in multiplayer simulation with Box2D, and single computer

Tags: box2d, multiplayer

I wrote a small test car driving multiplayer game with Box2D using TCP server-client communcations.

I ran 1 instance of server.exe and 2 instance of client.exe on the same machine that I code and compile the executables. I type inputs (WASD for a simple car movement) into one of the 2 clients and I can get both clients to update the simulation.

There are 2 cars in the simulation. As long as the cars do not collide, I get the same identical output on both client.exe. I can run the car(s) around for as long as I could they still update the same. However, if I start to collide the cars, very quickly they go out of sync.

My tools: `Windows 7, C++, MSVS 2010, Box2D, freeGlut`.

My Psuedocode:

```
// client.exe
void timer(int value)
{
   tcpServer.send(my_inputs);
   foreach(i = player including myself) inputs[i] = tcpServer.receive();
   foreach(i = player including myself) players[i].process(inputs[i]);
   myb2World.step(33, 8, 6); // Box2D world step simulation
   foreach(i = player including myself) renderer.render(player[i]);

   glutTimerFunc(33, timer, 0);
}

// server.exe
void serviceloop
{
    while(all clients alive)
    {
       foreach(c = clients) tcpClients[c].receive(&inputs[c]);

       // send input of each client to all clients
       foreach(source = clients)
       {
          foreach(dest = clients)
          {
              tcpClients[dest].send(inputs[source]);
          }
       }
    }
}
```

I have read all over the internet and SE the following claims (paraphrased):

1. Box2D is deterministic as long as floating point
   architecture/implementation is the same.
2. (For any deterministic engine) Determinism is gauranteed if playback of recorded inputs is on the same machine with exe compiled using same compiler and machine.

Additionally my server.exe and client.exe gameloop is single thread with blocking socket calls and fixed time step.

**Question: Can anyone explain what I did wrong to get different Box2D output?**

Comment: finally got attetion. Any clues anyone?

Comment: It seems like it would be trivial to attach a debugger or put in some tracing code and see at which operations they diverge. There's just not enough information here to help you without first building an entire toy simulation that might bear no resemblance to your own.

Comment: I suspect that you have to (really) fix your timestep. http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/ glutTImerFunc is not accurate enough.

Comment: Have you read the Box2D FAQ?  Probably not, because it has a section on determinism...  http://code.google.com/p/box2d/wiki/FAQ

Comment: @PatrickHughes I read the FAQ but it's vague to me. "For the same input, and same binary, Box2D will reproduce any simulation" -- so is it yes or no? Why can't it answer directly?

Comment: @kaoD I read that article already. I think although my "timestep" of 33ms is not really 33ms, but all clients are synchronised due to the blocking socket calls. i.e. if client X step simulation N times, then all other also step N times, each step is a const 33 delta time in b2World.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig I have minimal experience debugging server-client multiuser setups. So I have a bit of struggle. furthermore, I need to confirm the problem is not in Box2D first, which I still cannot get the answer, each time is see an answer, it is just beating around the bush. (see patrick hughes)

Comment: @Jake: "I need to confirm the problem is not in Box2D first" - No you don't. You debug to figure out where the problem is. If the client/server setup is bothering you for some reason, run both clients and the server in the same process. Without e.g. your test code, no one can tell you what if anything you're doing wrong.

Comment: This design may be too sophisticated for your current skill level.  Please try the architectural change that @JoeWreschnig suggests before continuing, it is less complex and will let you focus on the immediate problem.  Personally I suggest you then move to a proper server authoritative and client predictive architecture, it is scalable, resistant to cheating and glitches in timing whereas deterministic simulations fall apart at the first disparity (as you've noticed).

Comment: @PatrickHughes Can I humbly direct a simple question to you please: Is Box2D deterministic, given the same code, same compiler, running 2 separate instances in the same computer with exactly the same inputs (ie. I send single keyboard input to both instances), with the same number of simulation steps and fixed const time step?

Comment: @JoeWreschnig I don't understand, why don't I need to confirm whether Box2D is deterministic first? I definitely think I should know my tools first even before I start coding to have anything to debug in the first place. From the vague FAQ (to me only, I have bad English I suppose) I had the impression that Box2D is deterministic (see my definition above) so I wrote a simple setup to test and I find it to behave otherwise. That's the primary reason this question is here. Is not about the client-server setup. If I run my own bad physics replacing b2World.Simulation(), everything syncs.

Comment: My suggestion was to debug _to determine if Box2D is deterministic_. The FAQ says it is, but obviously it could have a bug. Since you refuse to debug your code who knows.

Comment: Interesting question - I'm also struggling with a determinism question where box2D is involved. I'm hashing and comparing most of the state on my two machines, and it seems they first diverge in the positions I get from box2D. I'll keep you posted if I find anything...

Comment: @Jake: You already seem to have a good case to debug the code. If you just "log" the input you get on an instance and replay it a few times, you should end up with different results, if box2d does indeed have a bug

Comment: @itjax thanks for following up. I have changed my code related to inputs and so far there were only 2 instances where the simulations diverged. And I cannot seem to replicate it easily. Currently running the simulations for an extended amount of time on different machines to see if I can reproduce the issue. As of now, it's hard to re-post my problem into a proper question.

Comment: I don't want to blame box2d preemptively, but it seems like it avoids default-initialization of lower-level constructs. If an uninitialized variable slipped though somewhere, that would very well explain the behavior.

Comment: Maybe you could try posting your code to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).  As it is, I think the question is a little vague.

Comment: +1 This question can still be saved by changing the core question focus around a bit, and a new title...

Comment: I can't determine the full scope of your implementation but try updating derivative values (velocity, acceleration). Additionally the problem here is that you are processing input at differing times: your input happens ms or ns apart in the two different simulations - which can lead to vastly different results.

Answer (score 1):

<del>Maybe glutTimerFunc(33, timer, 0); produce different results on different machines. Another thing is that your code.
takes different amount of time to execute every once you run it (especially on different computers), so that may be the source of desynchronization.</del>

Anyway the right way to do what you want to achieve is to run main physics simulation on server and send results to clients. You can avoid lag by making clients run their own simulation for results to use in time between getting results from the server.

Comment: If you see my code again, I block until I receive all clients' inputs before I process them for client update. Clients do not step simulation more than once between two tcpServer.receive();

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry. Still second part of my answer is valid. You can't rely on clients simulations, clients may cheat. EDIT: just random thought: are bodies in collection in the same order on both clients? Order matter in floating point operations.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your very constructive suggestion. I actually got the bodies collection in the same order, but you made me realise there may be a race condition between glutKeyboardFunc and glutTimerFunc... I just need to check now.

Comment: `glutKeyboardFunc` isn't even in any of your example code, reinforcing my point that you need to do more before we can help you. This question is quickly devolving into "guess my mistake" and I can't even vote to close it because you put a bounty on it. :(

Comment: Maybe you are imagining me sitting on a couch drinking coffee while waiting for others to guess my mistake. Sorry to say, I am actually trying all ways to debug. Perhaps if you are interested in the bounty, you could at least suggest which part of my code you want to see. Or simply comment whether my steps as posted presents any sync issues and *guess* where else I can look at. I will appreciate that, really. Afterall, guessing is not bad a technique especially when you have problems never encountered before.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that the two cars are out of sync due to the cars not syncing, I guess. I would do something like this:

```
//client
void tick() {
    step(a,b,c)
    for(body in myb2World) {
        if(body.userdata.owner == this) {
            tcpServer.send(body);
        }
    }
}

//server
void serviceloop
{
    while(all clients alive)
    {
       foreach(c = clients) tcpClients[c].receive(&inputs[c]);

       // send input of each client to all clients
       foreach(source = clients)
       {
          foreach(dest = clients)
          {
              tcpClients[dest].send(inputs[source]);
          }
       }
    }
}
```

and at the client the bodies not of that client are updated  with the correct state.